# Is there a hadeeth which states that homosexuality is adultery?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, homosexuality, zina, adultery

I seem to remember coming across a hadeeth which states that homosexuality is adultery.

Can someone please confirm this and if possible provide the hadeeth in its wording and source and strength?

jazakhalakhairan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This hadeeth was narrated by al-Bayhaqi from Abu Moosa (may Allaah be pleased with him), who said that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “If a man has sexual relations with another man, they are both guilty of zina, and if a woman has sexual relations with another woman they are both guilty of zina.”

This hadeeth is da’eef (weak); it was classed as da’eef by al-Albaani in Da’eef al-Jaami’, 282